# Match values between parenthesis with regex

Tags: regex, awk

We trying to get the value between the parenthesis using awk in this expression:

```
result = ( month(var1) == month(var2) && year(var3) == year(var4));
```

We tried diferents regex on similar questions like  `/\(([^)]+)\)/`

but didn´t work.

What is the best way to get these variables values ("var1","var2" etc..) between the parenthesis?

Edit:
What we trying to do is replace  "month(var1)" to "var1.getMonthValue()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{
  while(match($0,/month\([^)]*|year\([^)]*/)){ 
    var=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) 
    gsub(/month\(|year\(/,"",var)
    print var
    var=""
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}'  Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
var1
var2
var3
var4
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation of above code.

```
awk '{                                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
  while(match($0,/month\([^)]*|year\([^)]*/)){           ##Using while loop which will run till a match regex is found.
                                                         ##how match works is it will look for regex provided and set 2 default variables named RSTART and RLENGTH as per match.
    var=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                        ##creating a variable named var whose value is a sub string of current line starting point is RSTART and ending point is RLENGTH.
    gsub(/month\(|year\(/,"",var)                        ##using gsub to Globally substitute everyting from month OR year to till ( in matched regex.
    print var                                            ##Printing variable var here.
    var=""                                               ##Nullifying variable var here.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                         ##Setting value of current line whose value is sub string of current line starting from value of RSTART+RLENGTH, to make sure already matched values are NOT coming again.
  }                                                      ##Closing BLOCK for while loop here.
}'  Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file                                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: We tried using directly gsub without the loop, but this problem is  in stand by now. Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function names can only contain a-z, A-Z or 0-9:

```
echo 'result = ( month(var1) == month(var2) && year(var3) == year(var4));' | awk '                                                                                                                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  while (match($0, /[a-z0-9A-Z]\(([^)]+)\)/, a)) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    print a[1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}'
```